# How tweak the following features in outlook journal

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, journaled

1. I want to set which emails show up in journal
2. I want tasks created and completion to show up in journal
3. I got thousands of contact. As for #1 i want to disable journaling for all and then select a few. Currently thousands are journaled.